# Setting a vector drawable to meet the Splash Screen API requirement

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, android-splashscreen

Using the Android Splash Screen API,the requirements for putting an icon with no background on splashcreen is this: "App icon without an icon background: this must be 288×288 dp and fit within a circle 192 dp in diameter."
I'm new to android development,I have the vector drawable,how can I acheive this requirement?

Comment: @ganjaam What exactly do I edit to meet the requirements. I use inskcape.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for your splash screen icon. Simply i'm making it follow the requirements:

ic_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="48dp"
        android:left="48dp"
        android:right="48dp"
        android:top="48dp">
        <vector xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
            android:width="192dp"
            android:height="192dp"
            android:viewportWidth="192"
            android:viewportHeight="192">
            <path...
        </vector>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```